# Amazon S3 - GetPreSignedUrlRequest Works on my development machine, but not when the code is uploade to the web server

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am have a function in c# (WebForms code-behind) that creates a URL to my images stored on the Amazon S3 cloud server (code shown below).  When I run it on my development system it works fine, but when I run it on the production .NET web server, it fails (the URL's to my image files just result in a broken image icon on the web page).

The URL's seem to be the same in each case, except:
1) On the dev machine, the URL contains forward slashes (but other special characters are escaped) and on the production machine, the forward slashes are escaped (%5C)
2) The signature is different (as I would expect)

When I copy&paste the URL from the production machine into my local browser, it does not work, but I figure that's because it is including some id of the machine that calculated the URL in the signature.

Why does the exact same code work on one machine but not the other?

```
    public string CalculateURL
    {
        // build a url with the AWS credentials to get the file from the Amazon S3 cloud storage
        get
        {
            string secretKey = "secretkeygoeshere";
            string accessKey = "accesskeygoeshere";
            string url = "";

            BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
            AmazonS3Config asConfig = new AmazonS3Config()
            {
                ServiceURL = "s3.amazonaws.com",
                RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1
            };

            s3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, asConfig);
            GetPreSignedUrlRequest preSignedURLreq = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest() { Key = relative_path, BucketName = "my-bucket-name", Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12) };
            url = s3.GetPreSignedURL(preSignedURLreq);

            return url;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could the clock on your server be wrong?

Comment: *the forward slashes are escaped (%5C)*  `%5C` is not a forward / slash.  It's a \ backslash.  Perhaps that gives you some idea?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Turns out, the prod database had older data in it that used backslashes, whereas the development database on my computer had forward slashes.  When I updated the prod table with the dev data, all magically started working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a suggestion in one of the comments, I found the problem:   Turns out, the prod database had older data in it that used backslashes, whereas the development database on my computer had forward slashes. When I updated the prod table with the dev data, all magically started working.